# Facebook App Privacy Policy URL - What should I do if I am not a company? And I don't use any data from user netiher?

Tags: privacy, policy

I have a simple Facebook page, where I post 1 picture / day. (I am a regular person, don't have a company)

It would be boring, so a friend of mine created a Python script, so I can schedule this task every day, automated, without manual work.

The "App" is ready, but it requests Privacy Policy and Terms and Conditions....

This is just a simple Facebook Page, posting 1 picture / day.
I am not a company, it's just a hobby yet. (maybe later will be a company but not now)

I don't need login data, age, gender and so on. I just post and that's all.

What could I do? I feel stucked with this.

Thank you very much, have a nice day!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a policy question that should be directed to Facebook support, and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. We cannot speak on behalf of off-site third party vendors or service providers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly about programming or coding or programming tools or software algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use one of the content policy creator online, this will help you with some pre-filled details to make use of.

Example: https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/free-privacy-policy-generator.php

It helps you to choose whether options like the `age, gender, and so on` should be included on not. We you are done, you can download as HTML, host it on you server and provide the details in your Facebook app basic settings[image]